# Where do I destroy a Dialog if I create it dynamically?

Tags: qt, qml

Assume I have the following Dialog in QML:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Dialog
{
    title: "Bot Settings"
    modal: true
    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel

    property var bot1

    onAccepted: {}

    onRejected: {}

    Component.onCompleted: {}

    Component.onDestruction: {}
}
```

and I create it with a code like this:

```
function openBotDialog()
{
    var dynamicComp = Qt.createComponent("BotDialog.qml")
    var dynamicDlg = dynamicComp.createObject(mainWindow, {"bot1" : bot});
    dynamicDlg.open()
}
```

and I need to destroy the dialog when it closes.

What code do I use and where do I add it?

Should I destroy `dynamicComp`?

See the full source code of the [app with my dialog on GitHub](https://github.com/dmitriano/GcBug).

**EDIT1**

When I press the following buttons in my app the dialog is not destroyed by GC:

[image]

But when I press "Clear Dynamic Dlg" button that explicitly calls `destroy()` method the Dialog is destroyed and its `Component.onDestruction` handler is called.

```
        Button
        {
            text: "Clear Dynamic Dlg"
            onClicked:
            {
                dynamicComp.destroy()
                dynamicComp = null
                dynamicDlg.destroy()
                dynamicDlg = null
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should never destroy objects by yourself, it's Javascript there is a garbage collection for that. Read more [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#deleting-objects-dynamically)

Comment: @folibis Are you sure? From your link: Each instance runs a NumberAnimation, and when the animation has finished, calls destroy() on its root object to destroy itself. Should not I do something like this?

Comment: @folibis test it for yourself with my sample app, see EDIT1.

Comment: You can do that but you  shouldn't. There is a garbage collection that designed to do it automatically, when an object goes out of use.

Comment: @folibis Can't figure out when the Dialog I created goes out of use, it probably never happens in my app. When I call `gc()` after the dialog closed it is not destroyed. I tried to wait some time and call `gc()` but without a success.

Comment: You can destroy dynamically created object by calling `destroy()` But you cannot destroy object created by QtQuick

Comment: @folibis test the app and make the Dialog destroy

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    onAccepted: Qt.callLater(destroy)
    onRejected: Qt.callLater(destroy)
```

This means you are scheduling a destroy after the accepted/rejected signals are received. `Qt.callLater` adds enough of a delay so that the destruction isn't being done during the signal handler but immediately after.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: thisPage
    Button {
        text: qsTr("Bot Dialog")
        onClicked: openBotDialog()
    }
    function openBotDialog()
    {
        var dynamicComp = Qt.createComponent("BotDialog.qml")
        var bot = new Date();
        var dynamicDlg = dynamicComp.createObject(thisPage, {"bot1" : bot});
       dynamicDlg.open()
    }
}

//BotDialog.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Dialog
{
    title: "Bot Settings"
    modal: true
    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
    property var bot1
    onAccepted: Qt.callLater(destroy)
    onRejected: Qt.callLater(destroy)
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?code=import%20QtQuick%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20thisPage%0A%20%20%20%20Button%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Bot%20Dialog%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onClicked%3A%20openBotDialog()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20openBotDialog()%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20dynamicComp%20%3D%20Qt.createComponent(%22BotDialog.qml%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20bot%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20dynamicDlg%20%3D%20dynamicComp.createObject(thisPage%2C%20%7B%22bot1%22%20%3A%20bot%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dynamicDlg.open()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2FBotDialog.qml%0Aimport%20QtQuick%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%0ADialog%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Bot%20Settings%22%0A%20%20%20%20modal%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20standardButtons%3A%20Dialog.Ok%20%7C%20Dialog.Cancel%0A%20%20%20%20property%20var%20bot1%0A%20%20%20%20onAccepted%3A%20Qt.callLater(destroy)%0A%20%20%20%20onRejected%3A%20Qt.callLater(destroy)%0A%7D)